# fltk change tab group programmatically

Tags: fltk

I am using fltk 1.3.2, I use Fl_Tabs class with Fl_Group classes.

I create groups and I want to change selected tab programmatically.

When tabs open it shows first tab, I want to change and for example second tab should be showed.

Is it possible? I couldn't find any resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the value method to set the current tab.  It needs the Group of the second tab to be passed in.

Reference http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.1/Fl_Tabs.html